# Framing a travelling salesman problem variation

Tags: optimization

I have an optimisation problem I want to understand and tackle.

I think it is a Travelling Salesman variation, where I want to find an answer to the question:

"What is the most efficient route for a set of Visits?"

The variables for this question are dependent on:

- Set of Visits logically within a daily window
- Each Visit has a Duration
- Some Visits have a fixed Start Time that must be adhered too.  The remaining Visits are not fixed in their Start Time.
- Visits are geocoded to provide distance + travelling time between all

My question is, is this a Travelling Salesman variation type problem?

If yes, how do I frame it as so?

If not, any nudge in the direction of how to frame it would be really appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "most efficient"? A sequence of visits that satisfies the constraints with the least distance traveled?

Comment: Also, does the vehicle need to return to the original location by the end of the day?

Comment: @Math1000 - yes, as you put it.  A sequence of visits that satisfies the constraints with the least distance travelled.

Comment: @Math1000 - the vehicles do not need to start and finish at the same point each day.